# LOV values are not coming into UI

Tags: siebel

There is a LOV field (F1) in one of the applet in which values are not coming as you click on it. I checked at 'Administration - data > List of values' and found that for this field, LOV records are created. From tools I have checked all the possible error of configuration due to which the values could not come into the field. However there is no error in configuration. I compared this field (F1) with another field of its type but with this field there is no issues. I don't understand why values are not coming in this field (F1) only

Kindly let me know what are the possible reason's due to which the vaules are not coming. Is it related with postion also? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Use LookupValue(LOV_TYPE, Language_Independent_Code) in Calculated value of a field.

Remember to check "Calculated" flag.

Be sure that LOV value is present in flat LOV screen.

Make sure that Active flag is checked and LOV_TYPE, LIC and Display Value are populated ....

for a given LOV_TYPE and LIC, Display value will be pulled.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check if the values in the LOV have 'Active' flag checked.
Next , check if the field in the BC has Picklist assigned to it and at lease one Pickmap. If there are multiple pickmaps, check if any one among them has 'Constrain' checked. Finally, in the applet, the 'Run Time' flag must be checked for the picklist to properly work.

If it still does not work, check if any statemaps have been created for them.